# How to link a scikit prediction model to flask static website?

Tags: python, flask, scikit-learn

I successfully made a scikit learn prediction model running on my localhost and now I am interested in adding this model to my flask static website. How can I do that? Any suggestions? I basically would like to add a link on the flask static website to the prediction model.

For example

static website running on localhost:5000 has the following code

```
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return  render_template('index.html')

`@app.route('/model')`     #This code is wrong but I am trying to add my
`def model():`             #model here  

    return  url_for('localhost:8080')

    @app.route('/contactus')
    def contactus():
        return  render_template('contactus.html')
```

Comment: Show exactly what you want to do with your predictive model

Comment: I want to add it to the @app.route and create a tab that's what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

first you need to save your model , make it persistant and you can upload it in the server and load it there  for that you will need sklearn [joblib](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html)  .

[here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-machine-learning-models-python-scikit-learn/) is a useful tutorial that explained what you realy  need :

Comment: Not exactley what I am looking for I have the model pickled and deployed and it already live in server I am just looking for a way to add it to a static website

Comment: What do you mean by added it to a static web site?? What you want to do?? Make predictions with the data from the static site?? Explain well i can help

Comment: Or add a short description for what your model do and what do you want to do with it in the static site